# Client-side dynamic asset URLs in the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

## TL;DR

I'm trying to dynamically generate an asset URL using HTML5 data elements, on the client-side. This means the asset name isn't available until runtime in the browser, which prevents ERB from pre-processing on the server.

Is there a work-around or best practice for handling such a situation?

## Background

I'm using the [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) charting plugin in a Rails application, which uses various SWF files to generate charts. I'm in the process of upgrading the application to Rails 3.1 and have placed these SWF files into `/vendor/assets/javascripts/fusion_charts`.

Within the application, I dynamically specify the type of chart to draw using HTML5 data attributes, like so:

```html
<%# ... metric.html.erb ... %>
<div id='chart-container' class='fusion-chart'
  data-chart-type='MSLine'
  data-source-url="<%= @metric.data_url %>">
```

Then I have a simple jQuery plugin written in CoffeeScript that pulls these data attributes and wires things to Fusion Charts:

```js
// ... charting_plugin.js.coffee ...
chart = new FusionCharts
  swfUrl: "/assets/fusion_charts/#{data.chartType}.swf"
chart.setJSONUrl data.sourceUrl
chart.render containerId
```

The problem I'm running into is the `swfUrl` argument. To follow the guidance offered in the [RoR Asset Pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), I should use the `asset_path` helper in ERB, but this won't work because `data.chartType` is bound on the client, at run-time, and can't be pre-processed server-side.

```
<# ... charting_plugin.js.coffee.erb: This won't work; data.chartType isn't defined ... %>
chart = new FusionCharts
  swfUrl: "<%= asset_path "fusion_charts/#{data.chartType}.swf" %>"
chart.setJSONUrl data.sourceUrl
chart.render containerId
```

## Work Arounds

The simplest work-around (the one I'm using currently) is to simply move the SWF files back into `/public/fusion_charts` and not worry about the asset fingerprinting complexity of the pipeline. That said, I'm new to the pipeline, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Is there a better way to handle client-side asset URLs like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to have a lookup table for swf files by chart type, eg:

```
var chartMap = {
<% 
chart_types.collect do |type|
  "#{type.to_json}: #{asset_path(type + '.swf')}"
end.join(",\n")
%>
};
```

Then add a function to get the correct path on the client side at runtime like so:

```
function chartPath(type) {
  return chartMap[type];
};
```

Then change your setup call to be:

```
chart = new FusionCharts
  swfUrl: chartPath(data.chartType)
```

IE, use ERB to build a list of all possible paths you'll need at asset compilation time, and then do a lookup at run time on the client.  (and of course you'll need to coffee script-ize the above - I'm not a coffee guy, I prefer latte's.  :-)